# Creating tibble returns error due to name

Tags: r, tibble

I have 2 vectors.  I am trying to create a tibble with all combinations of the 2 vectors with the following error.

```
C <- c(1,2,3,4)
G <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
tibble('C' = rep(C, each = length(G)), 'G' = rep(G, length(C)))
Error: Column `C` must be length 1 or 100, not 20
```

Error disappears when I rename column 'C' to column 'A' for example.
We also don't get the same error with a data.frame

I suspect length(C) takes 'C' value from the tibble.
Is this an intended behaviour?
If so can someone explain how this is useful in practice? (i.e how would someone take advantage of this in their code)

Comment: `expand.grid(C, G) %>% as.tibble()` ?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about this function.  But the question is less about what I am trying to achieve and more about the behaviour of tibbles

Comment: Because tibbles are an extension to data.frame, and not an exact drop-in replacement, you can do things like `tibble(a=1:3,b=a+1)` , where you can reference earlier created columns. And this sort of example shows exactly why that might be a problem. "*Arguments are evaluated sequentially, so you can refer to previously created variables.*" - https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/tibble.html

Comment: tyvm! if u post as answer i'll be happy to accept

Comment: `C` and `c` are both functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because tibbles are an extension to data.frame, and not an exact drop-in replacement, you can do things like:

```
tibble(a=1:3, b=a+1)
## A tibble: 3 x 2
#      a     b
#  <int> <dbl>
#1     1     2
#2     2     3
#3     3     4
```

...where you can reference earlier created columns. And your example is an instance of when that might be a problem.

To quote the manual:

> "Arguments are evaluated sequentially, so you can refer to previously
>   created variables."

Source: http://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/tibble.html

So in this case, the `C` in `rep(G, length(C))` is actually referencing the `tibblename$C` you just created, which is length 20, rather than the vector `C` in the global environment, which is length 4.